# Slow rendering html table using PHP

Tags: php, html, performance, html-table, rendering

I am trying to create a dynamic html table using PHP  and mysql.
Now I am executing the SQL and retrieve the records into an array, and then using "foreach" to create rows and cells. The SQL execution works very fast, the problem is (I think) in rendering the html table. There are less then 1000 rows and 3 columns, but it takes the page (actually popup) about 1.5 minutes to show up.

PHP code:

```
$j = 0;
        foreach ($theItems  as $k => $l) {
            $j++;
            $tableString = $tableString.'<tr id="row'.$j.'">';
            $tableString = $tableString.'<td class="text-left width40" style="padding-left: 10px;">'.preg_replace('(\\\)', '', urldecode($l->name)).'</td>';
            $tableString = $tableString.'<td class="width25"><div class="raty" data-name="'.$l->id.'[]"></div></td>';
            $tableString = $tableString.'<td class="center" width=35%><textarea name="'.$l->id.'[]"></textarea></td>';
            $tableString = $tableString.'</tr>';
            /*echo '<tr id="row'.$l->index.'">';
            echo '<td class="text-left width40" style="padding-left: 10px;">'.preg_replace('(\\\)', '', urldecode($l->name)).'</td>';
            echo '<td class="width25"><div class="raty" data-name="'.$l->id.'[]"></div></td>';
            echo '<td class="center" width=35%><textarea name="'.$l->id.'[]"></textarea></td>';
            echo '</tr>';*/
        }
```

After I finish creating the html string I echo it;
as i mentioned it takes about a minute and a half.

Comment: Try to use `setInterval(function(){},1000);` that will be helpful.

Comment: Sounds way too long for just 1000 rows. What happens if you comment the line with `preg_replace` in it ? @GaneshGaxy Uh ? What is the point of that ?

Comment: @GaneshGaxy: uh, exactly how does adding JS to this solve anything? There's no JS anywhere in OP's code.

Comment: @user1935014: have you checked what's happening during that 1.5 minutes? e.g. are you waiting 1.5 minutes for a response from the server? waiting 1.5 minutes for your browser to actually render the response? or some combination thereof?

Comment: thanks everyone!,
i found the problem : the div with 'class:raty' displays 10 stars, which means 10 images. i just have to fix this class.